# Running an eternal background Process using RX java

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android, reactive-streams

I am trying to build an application using RX java which needs to listen to a message broker. This listener should always be  up and must not block the main thread.

I am using the following code to create the observable which emits messages as soon as it receives the same.

```
public Observable<Message<byte[]>>  getObservable(){ 
return Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Message<byte[]>>) subscriber -> {
        if (!subscriber.isDisposed()) { 
                Scheduler.Worker deliveryWorker = **Schedulers.io().createWorker()**;  
                deliveryWorker.schedule(() -> {
                Message<byte[]>  receivedMessages = destination.receive();
              subscriber.onNext(receivedMessages );
                  });

        }

    })   
 .**observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())**;
} }
```

Now, when I execute the code, I  see that the program runs for a second and then completes.

***I am expecting this to run forever as subscriber.onComplete() is never invoked.***  Am I missing something, what needs to be done to make this worker run forever and receive messages ?

What am I missing here ? What needs to be done to make the observable up and running forever ?

I did my test in Eclipse and see that after the main method is executed no threads are alive ;

However If I change the observable to a blocking observable using the following code, the process does not exit  and runs forever.

```
 getObservable().blockingSubscribe(message->{print(message);})
 doSomething(); // this code is not executing
```

But at the same this blocks the main thread from executing further. This is not what i want .

What can be the solution to my problem?

Comment: Please read the [Getting started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation) from that section and on.

Comment: @akarnokd thak you for the clarification